# Cannot find dependency module from a test or another class in same folder

Tags: angular, typescript, mocha.js, angular9

We have many ts classes that import a file with constants. It is like a base dependency for our ts classes.

This is example of the TS class (see ServiceBase):

```
import { ServiceBase } from 'src/app/service-base';
export class SomeService {

  private url = ServiceBase.ApplicationUrl;

   constructor() { }
```

The test file:

```
    import * as chai from 'chai';
    import { SomeService } from './some.service';

   describe('SomeService', () => {
      let service: SomeService;
        beforeEach(() => {
          chai.should();
          service = new SomeService()
        });



        it('should be created', () => {
          let expected: any = (service == undefined);
          expected.should.be.false;
        });
    });
```

**Error:** 
Cannot find module `'src/app/service-base'`

How can I create instance of that class in a way that it finds the ServiceBase path when the service is instantiated via the test (or even any other ts class)?

The test file is in the same folder as any of the TS classes. So if the ts class finds that ServiceBase, the test should be able to as well.

```
src/app/services/someservice
--some-service.ts
--some-service.test.ts
src/app/
--service-base.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to indicate the `service-base` file.

if this file is located to same level with `some.service`, you have to put like this: `import { ServiceBase } from './service-base';`.
maybe this will be work.

Comment: Thank you! I put the import for ServiceBase in the test, but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Using relative path seem to have fixed the problem:

```
import { ServiceBase } from 'src/app/service-base';
```

to

```
import { ServiceBase } from '../../service-base';
```